# Nosql relation alternate like firebase

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Looking for some guidance to figuring out the proper database.

I have been using Firebase but online for a database. I need to now use it offline

Our code base uses firebases ability to allow you to say the exact path to an element in the database and update..

Such as 
Firebase.update ('playername1/name'.set ('joe bob')

Does that make sense? I think its a nature of nosql.. but the ability to update by path is very important.

Comment: So what's the question here, are you looking for an offline alternative to firebase, or do you want to use firebase database without an internet connection?

Comment: Sorry.. should have been more clear.. looking for an offline alternate that works similar to firebase.. with a tree structure and allows you to update items by paths in the tree